# Images are not displaying in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Iam very new to drupal.

And i have drupal site. I am adding images through admin side(crate content->image).

```
Where can i see this image on client side ?
```

I dont know the url of the image displaying section.

Can any one please help?

Comment: Create content -> Image?

Did you create a content-type called 'image' or are you adding images to a specific content type that are not displaying? 

Please elaborate and tell us exactly what you did/do.

Comment: i think the guy wants to upload an image via wysiwyg and embed it in the content. which is a problem for most people. 
if you just want to view the image, look through your content list and find the node. if you want to upload and insert an image, you'll need to install ckeditor or wysiwyg modules and integrate those with imce or some other form of file upload bridge. image nodes are pretty useless imo.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually really easy to add an image to your content so long as you have CCK and CKEditor modules installed.

When creating the CCK make sure File uploads is activated.

When you create the content, use the file upload section of the form, once the upload is done, then the url to the image will be displayed.

Using the CKEditor, just add image and plug in that url.

Image inserted and problem solved